# Unable to access Tomcat server from Java servlet

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I have a simple *Hello World* "Dynamic Web Application" written in JavaEE IDE Luna. I have the latest version of Tomcat installed, and I pointed Eclipse to it, by going to the "Servers" tab at the bottom. I added the server, and added my Jar to it. The server started successfully. However, when I go to `http://localhost:8080/` I get an HTML page from the server with the warning:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /
```

This tells me that the server is running but somehow my `doGet()` method isn't routed correctly. Here is the code for my `doGet()`.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 

    ServletException, IOException {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter output = response.getWriter();
            output.println("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
        }
```

Other server programs like webapp2 and node, allow me to specify something like:

`app.get('/',function(req,res){//stuff});`

but none of the starter tutorials for Servlets mentioned this kind of URL routing.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How are you calling that servlet?

Comment: Not enough information: You say you "added your jar to it" - I'd expect your webapplication (war) to be deployed to tomcat. Does tomcat's log indicate your application to be deployed? What context is it deployed in? It might require localhost:8080/your-app-name/ to access it

Comment: @OlafKock, I just added it as a "confguration". How do I find the `.war` file?

Answer (score 2):

you write your web.xml file following content then

```
<servlet>
     <servlet-name>name</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>classname</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>name</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>   //'hello' your url pattern
</servlet-mapping>
```

put url in browser

localhost:8080/appname/hello

http://howknowledge.com

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's still not working, but I do have another question. Does each URL endpoint have to have its own servlet?